# How can I give a background color for '\bibentry'

Tags: tcolorbox, backgrounds, bibentry

How can I give a background color for `\bibentry`? Something like that (by using `\bibentry{ahlswede2000network}`):

> Bibentry: Ahlswede, R., Cai, N., Li, S.-Y. R., and Yeung, R. W. (2000). Network information
>   flow. Information Theory, IEEE Transactions on, 46(4):1204–1216

Here is an entry to test.

```
@article{ahlswede2000network,
  title={Network information flow},
  author={Ahlswede, Rudolf and Cai, Ning and Li, Shuo-Yen Robert and Yeung, Raymond W},
  journal={Information Theory, IEEE Transactions on},
  volume={46},
  number={4},
  pages={1204--1216},
  year={2000},
  publisher={IEEE}
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want a background color in the .bib file? Or perhaps your entry is an example of code in a document? Please clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox)and a redefinition of `\bibenty`. A little example (adjust the settings according to your needs):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}

\definecolor{bibentrybg}{RGB}{249,245,233}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\bibentry[1]{
\begin{tcolorbox}[
  breakable,
  enhanced jigsaw,
  boxsep=0pt,
  arc=0pt,
  outer arc=0pt,
  frame code={},
  interior code={
    \fill[bibentrybg] (interior.north west) rectangle (interior.south east);
    \draw[double] (interior.north west) -- (interior.north east);
    \draw[double] (interior.south west) -- (interior.south east);
  }
]%
  \nocite{#1}{\frenchspacing
  \hyper@natanchorstart{#1\@extra@b@citeb}%
  \@nameuse{BR@r@#1\@extra@b@citeb}\hyper@natanchorend}
\end{tcolorbox}  
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{xyyzzz.bib}
@article{ahlswede2000network,
  title={Network information flow},
  author={Ahlswede, Rudolf and Cai, Ning and Li, Shuo-Yen Robert and Yeung, Raymond W},
  journal={Information Theory, IEEE Transactions on},
  volume={46},
  number={4},
  pages={1204--1216},
  year={2000},
  publisher={IEEE}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\nobibliography*
\bibentry{ahlswede2000network}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{xyyzzz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If the box should be applied to just selected boxes, no redefinition of `\bibentry` is required; simply enclose the `\bibentry` in the `tcolorbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}

\definecolor{bibentrybg}{RGB}{249,245,233}

\newtcolorbox{MyBox}{
  breakable,
  enhanced jigsaw,
  boxsep=0pt,
  arc=0pt,
  outer arc=0pt,
  leftrule=0pt,
  rightrule=0pt,
  colback=bibentrybg,
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{xyyzzz.bib}
@article{ahlswede2000network,
  title={Network information flow},
  author={Ahlswede, Rudolf and Cai, Ning and Li, Shuo-Yen Robert and Yeung, Raymond W},
  journal={Information Theory, IEEE Transactions on},
  volume={46},
  number={4},
  pages={1204--1216},
  year={2000},
  publisher={IEEE}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\nobibliography*

\begin{MyBox}
\bibentry{ahlswede2000network}
\end{MyBox}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{xyyzzz}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps a specialized `\newtcolorbox` would 'improve' the configurability?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Sure. Answer updated.

Comment: Can't upvote again ;-)

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thx. How can I get rid of borders (lines)?